# VBA Arrays to delete entire column

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

This code is an attempt to delete columns that contain Header rows that match the “Text” in the Array (list).

The code successfully deletes the column based on the 1st array value "Header Text 1".

The problem occurs during the 2nd pass of the loop on `A.EntireColumn.Delete`.  When I print the `vItem`, it displays the expected “Header Text 2” value, which is the correct item in the array.

> VBA Error – Runtime error ‘91’
>
> Object variable or With block variable not set

```
Sub ArrayLoop()
Dim ColumnsToRemove As Variant
Dim vItem As Variant
Dim A As Range

ColumnsToRemove = Array("Header Text 1", "Header Text 2", "Header Text 3")

For Each vItem In ColumnsToRemove

    Set A = Rows(1).Find(What:=(ColumnsToRemove), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)
    Debug.Print vItem
    A.EntireColumn.Delete

Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to search for vitem I think

Answer (score 3):

You need to look for `vItem`, and you need to add a check to see if it was found before trying to delete the column it's in.

```
Sub ArrayLoop()
Dim ColumnsToRemove As Variant
Dim vItem As Variant
Dim A As Range

ColumnsToRemove = Array("Header Text 1", "Header Text 2", "Header Text 3")

For Each vItem In ColumnsToRemove

    Set A = Rows(1).Find(What:=vItem, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                          lookat:=xlPart)

    Debug.Print vItem, Not A Is Nothing

    If Not A Is Nothing Then A.EntireColumn.Delete

Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Just curious if you know any advantage or disadvantage, with an array, in using `for each x in array` instead of using the l- and ubound, as in my answer? Or is it just the same?

Comment: @BruceWayne - not sure it matters: I used `For Each` here because that's what the OP had used.  EDIT: you can't use For each if you want to update the array member in the loop.  Not applicable here though.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on updating the array, and yeah I figured you just did that since OP did. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub ArraybLoop()
Dim ColumnsToRemove() As Variant
Dim vItem As Variant
Dim A As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim Sht As Worksheet

Set Sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

ColumnsToRemove = Array("Header Text 1", "Header Text 2", "Header Text 3")


    For i = LBound(ColumnsToRemove) To UBound(ColumnsToRemove) Step 1
        vItem = Application.Match(ColumnsToRemove(i), Sht.Rows(1), 0)

        Debug.Print vItem

        If IsNumeric(vItem) Then Sht.Columns(vItem).Delete
    Next i

End Sub
```

[Upper and Lower Bounds](http://www.bettersolutions.com/vba/VAA733/MN623314332.htm)

[Understanding Arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164778%28v=office.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: I like this - using `Match` removes the need to check for if there's no match, correct? Because for `vItem` to be numeric, you'd have to have a match, right?  Clever!  My way is a little more wordy :/

Answer (score 1):

A way to loop through an index is to use `ubound` and `lbound`:

```
Sub ArrayLoop()
Dim ColumnsToRemove As Variant
Dim vItem As Variant
Dim A As Range
Dim i As Long

ColumnsToRemove = Array("Header Text 1", "Header Text 2", "Header Text 3")


For i = LBound(ColumnsToRemove) To UBound(ColumnsToRemove)
    Set A = Rows(1).Find(what:=ColumnsToRemove(i), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)
    Debug.Print ColumnsToRemove(i) ' not sure what `vItem` was intended to be
If A Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "Nothing found"
ElseIf Not A Is Nothing Then
    A.EntireColumn.Delete
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice, looks like we post at the same time